# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka DLQ via Retryable/Recover

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka, spring-retry

My usecase is to receive Kafka messages, make multiple attempts at a rest call and upon exhaustion dump the failed mesage onto Kafka DLQ topic.

```
    @StreamListener(EventSource.SOME_CHANNEL)
    public void processMessage(Message<?> unsolicitedMessage) {
         String aString = .....   
         oneService.act(aString);      
    }
```

`@Retryable` is working perfectly in terms of handing logic for multiple attempts.

```
    @Retryable(value = {OneException.class, TwoException}, maxAttempts = 3, 
    backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))
    public boolean act(String message, String endPoint) {
         //do stuff
    }
```

For the Spring Cloud Stream inbuilt Kafka DLQ publishing to kick in (`enableDlq: true`) , the exception needs to bubble-up to the `@StreamListener` annotated method for the Kafka binder to do the needful.

However, in doing so, I am not able to leverage the `@Recover` annotated method, where the flow perfectly lands *after retrying*:

```
@Recover
public boolean recoverOnToDLQ(OneException ex, String message, String 
endPoint) {
    throw ex; //Required for StreamListener Kafka DLQ to kick in! 
}
```

**Question:** Is there a way to trigger  Kakfa DLQ publishing from within the `@Recover` method without re-throwing the exception?

Because if I use it only to rethrow, I believe I won't be making efficient use of the tighter control obtained therein. This will also simplify unit test cases, and better capture the logic at code-level? Are there any thoughts on how to handle this better?

I am on all the latest versions for spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream and spring-retry as of this date.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, but the question is "why would you want to?".

The binder has retry built in; simply throw the exception back to the binder and it will send the data to the DLQ after retries are exhausted. Retry is configured using binder consumer retry properties. You would not need one line of additional code.

By using `@Retryable`, you are nesting 2 `RetryTemplate`s (unless you are disabling the binder retry by setting the consumer `maxAttempts` property to 1).

Of course, you can configure your own DLQ destination and simply write whatever you want to that in your recoverer. But, to use the binder's built-in DLQ publisher you'd have to craft a special `ErrorMessage` (with the properties the publisher needs) and send it to the binding's error channel. The publisher needs the raw kafka `ConsumerRecord` which you would have to re-create since it's not available to the listener.

All-in-all, for your use case, it seems much simpler to just use the binder's retry config.

**EDIT**

In 2.0.x you can add a `RetryTemplate @Bean` to your application and it will be used for all consumer bindings (overriding the binding properties).

This template can be customized with any retry policy, retryable exceptions, etc, etc.

In 2.0.2 it will have to be qualified with `@StreamRetryTemplate`; this was a fix because **any** `RetryTemplate` overrides the properties, which may not be the desired behavior.

Comment: Hi @Gary Russell, thank you. 
Yes, leveraging out of the box usage by plugging in consumer params in YML works like a charm. 
The `retry` mechanism needs to trigger only for specific errors (unauthorized, unavailable). For all others (bad request, business error etc.) message can go directly in DLQ. Out of the box (config-based) will retry every error message?
Hence the thought of actual implementation to cover individual scenarios, and customize error log. We can also build robust unit/mock tests specifically around our use cases (e.g. n-retries vs. 1 retry, etc.)

Comment: See the edit to my answer; you can provide a custom `RetryTemplate` to be used by the binder instead of the binding properties.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell, could you suggest please how to add recovery method for `@StreamRetryTemplate`, so I could write logic after retries exhausted. I'm using rabit-mq binder and I don't want to send messages to dlq, I just want to save to db error message and finish.

Comment: Don't ask new questions on old answers; you can't currently do that, but you **can** add a custom error handler to the listener container; if you need me to show you how; ask a new question; I don't want to pollute this answer with unrelated information.

Comment: I monitor the tags so I get automatice notification.